# Meteor & Mup - minor edits on remote

Tags: meteor, deployment, meteor-up

I am using meteor and mup to deploy, every time I make a change I run

```
mup deploy
```

Is there away to deploy individual files or even edit on the server as this process is very slow. Mup deploy takes about 20 minutes.

Comment: Note that you need to run `mup setup` as well, not just `mup deploy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck, but you could alternatively use `git` to synchronize your code base between your local machine and your remote server, and then run meteor in production mode to replicate production environment.

```
ROOT_URL="..." MONGO_URL="..." METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat settings.json) meteor --port=80 --production
```

You need to make sure you run `meteor` with the same environment variables that `mup` would use to make sure you're testing the exact same configuration.

Then just run `git pull` in your distant Meteor app directory and the remote server will automatically fetch your latest codebase as well as restart the app accordingly for you to test online.

You could also use `Dropbox` to synchronize your app source code between your local machine and the remote server and you'll have CTRL+S instant hot code push on your remote webserver, how cool is that ?